# Serializing a queryset in dehydrate

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm trying to expose a whole queryset in my tastypie dehydrate method:

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    bundle.data['stuff'] = serializers.serialize('json', Stuff.objects.filter(object_id=object_id))
    return bundle
```

I can't figure out how to do this though. The above example puts it in tastypie as a string. I've also tried calling .values() instead of using django.core's serializer but that also stuffs it into tastypie as a string- what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess what you want is a dictionary so you could do something like this:

```
bundle.data['stuff'] = [st.__dict__ for st in Stuff.objects.all()]
```

This will return some info you probably don't need but is a good start.